# Finding the maximum value of a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, max

I would like to find the maximum value of a variable (column) and then retain this value (the maximum value) and all values below it. Along with these values, I would like to retain the corresponding values from all other variables (columns) within the data frame. I want to exclude all values above this point from the data frame, for all variables within it. Included is the script for an example data frame (df), and an expected data frame (df2) i.e. what I am trying to achieve. I would be so grateful for some script to do this.

```
Ba <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
Sr <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
Mn <- c(1,1,2,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Ba, Sr, Mn)

df

#   Ba Sr Mn
# 1  1  1  1
# 2  1  1  1
# 3  1  1  2
# 4  2  2  1
# 5  2  2  1
```

Showing 1 to 5 of 5 entries, 3 total columns

This is what I want to achieve in R:

```
Ba2 <- c(1,2,2)
Sr2 <- c(1,2,2)
Mn2 <- c(2,1,1)
df2 <- data.frame(Ba2, Sr2, Mn2)

df2

#   Ba2 Sr2 Mn2
# 1   1   1   2
# 2   2   2   1
# 3   2   2   1
```

Showing 1 to 3 of 3 entries, 3 total columns

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more what exactly you are trying to achieve? I.e. with your input `df` it's not clear to me how you'll get to your expected outcome values.

Comment: Also your input df is different from the text below the code which I assume is also supoosed to represent some data? "Ba Sr Mn 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 3 1 1 2 4 2 2 1 5 2 2 1 Showing 1 to 5 of 5 entries, 3 total columns"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `cummax`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   filter(cummax(invoke(pmax, cur_data())) == max(cur_data()))
  Ba Sr Mn
1  1  1  2
2  2  2  1
3  2  2  1
```

Comment: Thanks for your great feedback! I would like to do exactly that but I should have mentioned that I am using a list rather than a data frame and am interested in finding the max value of Mn specifically. I would like to retain this value (the maximum value of Mn) and all values below it. Along with these values, I would like to retain the corresponding values from all other variables (columns) within the list (i.e. Ba and Sr).

Comment: @AngelaRussell Is it a `list` of `data.frame` or simply a list.  Can you post as a new question as all the answers here are based on your data.frame input

Answer (score 2):

You can subset `df` with the sequence from `min` to `nrow(df)` of `which.max` per column:

```
df[min(sapply(df, which.max)):nrow(df),]
#  Ba Sr Mn
#3  1  1  2
#4  2  2  1
#5  2  2  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
df[max(apply(df, 1, which.max)):nrow(df),]
  Ba Sr Mn
3  1  1  2
4  2  2  1
5  2  2  1
```